# Proposition $6.9$ in Aluffi's Algebra: Chapter $0$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Proposition $6.9$: Let $G \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$ be a subgroup. Then $G = d\mathbb{Z}$ for some $d \geq 0,$ where $d\mathbb{Z} = \{m \in \mathbb{Z} | (\exists q \in \mathbb{Z})(m=dq) \}.$

In the proof, Aluffi takes $d$ to be the smallest positive integer in $G$. He also claims that if $a \in G,$ then $a$ must be positive, for if $a < 0$, then $-a > 0$. Then he says that the inclusion $d\mathbb{Z} \subseteq G$ is clear. But I don't see why it's clear.

My thinking: Let $m \in d\mathbb{Z}$. Then $m$ is some multiple of $d$. But how do we know that $m \in G$ and why is it clear? I can't get my head around this.

Comment: You may have misinterpreted (or anyway mis-reproduced) the book. $G$ may not have any positive elements. However, then it cannot have negative elements either (because, if $a\in G, a<0$, then $-a\in G$ (as $G$ is a subgroup - i.e. closed for operator $-$) so $-a$ would be a positive element - contradiction. Thus $G=\{0\}=0\mathbb Z=d\mathbb Z$ for $d=0$. Okay, that case aside, we can now consider the case where $G$ has positive elements, and let $d>0, d\in G$ be the smallest such element. The rest should be about proving that $G=d\mathbb Z$. (TBC)

Comment: (Cont'd) Now, $d\mathbb Z\subseteq G$ should be the easier part, and you've got some answers below. The opposite ($G\subseteq d\mathbb Z$) is actually, technically, a harder part.

Comment: @StinkingBishop You're absolutely right - I misinterpreted what he was saying. Thanks a lot for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

If $m \in d\mathbb{Z}$, then $m=kd$ for some integer $k$.

Note that
$$
\underbrace{d + d + \ldots + d}_{\text{$k$ times}} = m
$$
as a result. Since $d \in G$ and $G$ is a group, it is closed under addition; in particular, it is closed under repeat addition by $d$.

Answer (score 0):

$G$ is a subgroup so must be closed under the addition operation. So, $d+d=2d$ must be in $G$. So $2d+d=3d$ must be in $G$. By induction, $nd\in G$ for any $n\in\Bbb N$. But $G$ must also be closed under the inversion operation; thus, $-nd\in G$ for any $n\in\Bbb N$. And $0=0d\in G$ of course - therefore, $md\in G$ for any integer $m$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I edited my post to include this: "He also claims that if $a \in G,$ then $a$ must be positive, for if $a < 0$, then $-a > 0$." So how can we have $-nd \in G$?

Comment: @SleeveOfWizard See my comment to your post. I am not sure if this is your misinterpretation or is the error of the author, but obviously $G$ cannot be made of all-positive numbers. $G$ is a subgroup, so it is closed for the unary minus, so unless $G=\{0\}$ it has both positive and negative elements. The argument above seems like a garbled version of the real argument that _we can choose a positive element in $G$_ (so then we can choose the smallest such element).

Comment: I would personally phrase it as: "Suppose $G$ is not trivial, i.e. $G\ne\{0\}$. Then, pick a nonzero element $a\in G$. _Without loss of generality_ (WLOG) we can assume that $a>0$. This is because, if $a<0$, then $-a\in G$ and $-a>0$", etc. etc.